# Scala Play Max HTTP Connection

Tags: playframework, connection, threadpool, stress-testing, apachebench

With ab I can only have maximum 50 connections (with default configuration).

The ab command I use:

```
ab -n 50 -c 50 http://myipaddress.net:9000/
```

I tried increasing the memory limit in, so I invoke the start script this way:

```
sh $REST_DB_HOME/bin/siie-rest -Dhttp.port=9000 -J-Xms2048M -J-Xmx2048m -J-server -Dconfig.file=$REST_DB_HOME/conf/application.conf
```

It only helps a little, now max http connection is around 80.

So... I tried additional approach, configuring the thread pool, following this documentation:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.7/ThreadPools

I put this in my application.conf:

```
play {
  akka {
    akka.loggers = ["akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger", "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = WARNING
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-factor = 1.0
          parallelism-max = 130
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't really change anything. Still stuck with 85 http connections (maximum). Well, Ok, I hit the 100 connections sometimes.

Is there anything else I can do at the configuration level to improve this? For comparison: a tomcat webserver can consistently handle 100 connections, and it can withstand up to 130 connections.

I also read this: http://www.ybrikman.com/writing/2014/02/18/maxing-out-at-50-concurrent-connections/

Requires code changes.... Play's code change. Not the app code. So, no go for me.

Or should I just upgrade to latest version of Play?

Thanks,
Raka

Comment: Try increasing the `parallelism-factor`.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like that's the answer (I tried your advice and it works).